# Flutter WIth Django Rest Api to fetch data

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter. I have created a small project in django rest api where user can get the data Via API. I serialize the data and its working. In frontend i'm using flutter for my app. I did add the http(0.13.3) library in the pubspec.yaml. And i imported the package in my flutter project. Now the problem i'm facing is how to get the data from the API.

**This is how i get the data when i'm visiting my api in the browser -**

```
[{"author":{"username":"jhinku","first_name":"jhinku","last_name":"mamoni"},"content":""}]
```

**In flutter info.dart -**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final response = await http.get(MyAPIEndpoint);
Map response=jsonDecode(response.body);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 12,
      bottom: bottomPadding,
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 80),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'response['author']['username']',
           style: StandardTextStyle.big,
        ),
        Container(height: 6),
        Text(
          desc ?? 'OK',
          style: StandardTextStyle.normal,
        ),
        Container(height: 6),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.music_note, size: 14),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
               'here is another text',
                maxLines: 9,
                style: StandardTextStyle.normal,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I want to Put the Author from the REST-API.

```
Text(
        '@Author', #getting the author from the REST-API
        style: StandardTextStyle.big,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FutureBuilder` as it is the easiest to use for beginners

The above answer will work too, but this approach is way easier, especially when you know quite less about how asynchronous programming works in flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}


class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final Future<Map<String,dynamic> _calculation(){
      //Perform your API Call here
      final response = await http.get(APIEndpoint)
      return jsonDecode(response)
  }
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(  //This is mandatory to use
        future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<Map> 
                               //or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, 
                       AsyncSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                   // We have received the data here
                  //You can modify this code according to your case
            children = Container(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                   left: 12,
                   bottom: bottomPadding,
                   ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 80),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '$snapshot['author']['username']',
           style: StandardTextStyle.big,
        ),
        Container(height: 6),
        Text(
          desc ?? 'OK',
          style: StandardTextStyle.normal,
        ),
        Container(height: 6),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.music_note, size: 14),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
               'here is another text',
                maxLines: 9,
                style: StandardTextStyle.normal,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                   // The asynchronous operation failed
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              )
            ];
          } else {
           // snapshot.hasData is false so the data is still loading
            children = const <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              )
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here `_calculation` is just a simulation for any async operation such as the network call in your case. You can add your network call and related logic here

`FutureBuilder` will have different states implemented in the `AsyncSnapshot<T>` and so the user can be shown that an operation is in progress

Comment: This example was taken from the [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I did  edit the question with @JigarFumakiya answer but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey @Cavinblake, I have tried to edit my answer with what I was wanting you to do, see if that helps you, and if it does please upvote and mark the solution as accepted

Comment: Do i still need to use future builder after what you edited?

Comment: Any reason why you shouldn't ?

Comment: No there is no specific reason. I just don't know how to use it. I don't know how to add it in a the dependencies.

Comment: Then my friend, this is the time you learn it, and also it's just applying, I have already given you the template above with the comments, so I guess editing the code should be easy right?

Comment: Yeah..i need to add future builder in my dependencies..right?

Comment: FutureBuilder is present in the same dart package as the other widgets that you have used, i.e. material.dart

Comment: Also as an advice, you could also read the [dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) documentation on how asynchronous programming works in general. That will clear why a Futurebuilder was needed in flutter

Comment: The problem i'm facing that all the tutorials in the internet all are working on the  previous version of http packages. In the updated version they change the uri url parameters. I will definitely apply your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235351/discussion-between-cavin-blake-and-gtxtreme).

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can get the data from API.

```
final response = await http.get(APIEnpoint);

Map response=jsonDecode(response.body);
response['author']['username'] ---> here what you want
response['author']['first_name'] -->Change key values and get all data.
```

You can put this API call in init methods and after getting data you can do set state

Comment: I did edit the question with your solution, its giving me a bunch of errors.